# Can I use an org.apache package with BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, package

Can I use this code for a BlackBerry app?

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

If so, how do I import this package into Eclipse?

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop! thats not possible, the http connections that android uses are based on Apache, with a brief search over the internet you can find a lot of examples of how to do it in Blackberry!

here you can find a good example...
[Posting Data via Http from Blackberry](http://blog.copyninja.info/2009/09/posting-data-via-http-from-blackberry.html)